# Box2d static velocity faster on diagonal movement

Tags: javascript, box2d, velocity

So I want a snappy movement for my player. Right now my code looks like

```
  move() {
    var vel = this.body.GetLinearVelocity()

    if(!this.pressingDown && !this.pressingUp){
        vel.y = 0;
    }
    if(!this.pressingRight && !this.pressingRight){
        vel.x = 0;
    }

    if(this.pressingDown){
        vel.y = this.speed;
    }
    if(this.pressingUp){
        vel.y = -this.speed;

    }
    if(this.pressingRight){
        vel.x = this.speed;

    }

    if(this.pressingLeft){
        vel.x = -this.speed
    }
    this.body.SetLinearVelocity(vel)
```

and this works but when I'm moving diagnolly the player is moving faster than the max speed. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Determine the directional unit vector and then multiply it by `this.speed`. That way the magnitude of the velocity is always `this.speed`. Otherwise, as you discovered, your speed may be `sqrt(this.speed * this.speed * 2)` instead of just `this.speed`.

A way to determine this directional unit vector would be to recognize the angle you want to move at based on the keys pressed and then getting the sine and cosine values for that angle. So when `this.pressingRight`, the angle is 0. When `this.pressingUp`, the angle is 90 degrees (or Pi/2 radians). Or when `this.pressingUp && this.pressingRight`, the angle is 45 degrees (Pi/4 radians). Just complete the if-statement for all serviceable combinations. Perhaps put that in its own function called something like `getAngleInRadiansForKeyPresses`.

The implementation (in pseudo-javascript-code) might then look something like:

```
move() {
    var angle = getAngleInRadiansForKeyPresses();
    var vel = new b2Vec2(Math.cos(angle) * this.speed, Math.sin(angle) * this.speed);
    this.body.SetLinearVelocity(vel);
}
```